# gsub function, exact match of the pattern

Tags: r, text, gsub

I have a list of words included in the data frame called `remove`. I want to remove all the words in `text`. I want to remove the exact words.

```
remove <- data.frame("the", "a", "she")
text <- c("she", "he", "a", "the", "aaaa")

for (i in 1:3) {
  text <- gsub(data[i, 1], "", text)
}
```

Attached is the result returned

```
#[1] ""   "he" ""   ""   ""
```

However what I am expecting is

```
#[1] ""   "he" ""   ""   "aaaa"
```

I also tried the following code, but it does return the expected result:

```
for (i in 1:3) {
    text <- gsub("^data[i, 1]$", "", text)
    }
```

Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For exact match, use value matching (`%in%`)

```
remove<-c("the","a","she") #I made remove a vector too
replace(text, text %in% remove, "")
#[1] ""     "he"   ""     ""     "aaaa"
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple base R solution is:

```
text[!text %in% as.vector(unlist(remove, use.names = FALSE))]
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!